# Android Gui with Fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I was just curious if anyone could link me with some help or show me some code that would show a tab view with scrollable content like the pulse app both horizontal and vertical scroll content. I have it working entirely using TabActivity and Activity classes but I am have a really hard time converting it to either using fragments and or ActionBarTab setups since TabActivity has since been depreciated. It has been bothering me and I have been reading the API but I was just curious if there were any simple examples to where I could see how to set that up using FragmentActivity and Tab Manager or the ActionBar.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/). It is very neat and back-compatible.

Comment: Are there any copyrights on this or what not if my app product become profitable? Or is it all open source and non-infringable

Comment: It uses Apache 2.0 licence, so you can use it freely. You can check it from [project's github page](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock#license) and [here](http://www.apache.org/foundation/license-faq.html#IsItFee).